# Getting all news on a topic in Google News

Tags: google-news

I subscribe to a Google News RSS feed on a topic. To me it seems like the feed only gives me a digested version and doesn't show every news item with the terms.
Is there a way to tell Google News to provide all results?

Comment: What do you mean every news item with the terms?

Comment: @Christian can you provide a link to the news you subscribe to. Note that when you subscrive via email, you have the option to show only "best result" or "all results"

Answer (score 1):

Copy the url into a text editor and look for an ampersand.  Insert

> &num=20

in front of some existing ampersand.  Then paste the whole thing back into your browser.  This will give you 20 hits.  You can make the number bigger if you want to.